# Powershell не видит диск .С

Tags: powershell

Какую команду я бы не вводил Powershell дает ответ что нет диска .С
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1021310

Comment: ответ в том вопросе мне не помог, у меня попросту нет переменной патх с таким значением